# add the count of non-blank cells to the count of preceeding value VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to excel vba and I would like help with the problem I am facing.

[image]

I have put across a small example in the above link.
What I would like is to count the number of characters in each column in a defined range.
However if there are blank cells, then the blank cell gets counted to the preceding non-blank value.
In example 1: cells 3,4 are empty and their preceding non-blank value is R. So count of R becomes 4.
Cell 6 is empty as well and therefore gets added to the count of Y which is the preceding non-blank value. So count of Y is 2.

In example 2: cells 1,2 are empty however they don't have any preceding non-blank value and hence they are not counted.
Also, cells 4,5,6 are empty. However they have a preceding non-blank value Y.
So count of Y is 4

Can someone help me to code this in VBA?

Comment: Will there be a column with the Row data or are you just showing that to represent the rows in the spreadsheet?

Comment: Hi Matthew, I am just showing that to represent the rows in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Is it true that (a) it is necessary to preserve the blanks AND you are unable to append a column to the data?
Does this have to be done with VBA?
If both of those answers are no, then basic excel functionality can cover you here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have row index on column A and Data in column B and the data in your sheet starts from row number 3 (as shown on your image), I would suggest the following code :

```
    Sub test()
        Dim rowNum As Integer
        Dim prevRowData As String
        Dim rCount, yCount

        rowNum = 3
        prevRowData = ""
        rCount = 0
        yCount = 0
        Do While Trim(Range("A" & rowNum).Value) <> ""
                Select Case (Trim(Range("B" & rowNum).Value))
                 Case "R"
                    rCount = rCount + 1
                    prevRowData = "R"
                 Case "Y"
                    yCount = yCount + 1
                    prevRowData = "Y"
                 Case ""
                    If prevRowData = "R" Then
                      rCount = rCount + 1
                    ElseIf prevRowData = "Y" Then
                      yCount = yCount + 1
                    End If
                End Select
                rowNum = rowNum + 1
        Loop

        Range("A" & (rowNum + 1)).Value = "Count of R:" & rCount
        Range("A" & (rowNum + 2)).Value = "Count of y:" & yCount
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Animesh, your solution definitely worked. it had a small issue but it rectified it. The prevRowData was being compared with 'R' both times but it was minor. Thanks a lot for your help. It helped me resolve my issue. I was able to adapt the logic to my code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do it.  Something to note is that this will only go to the last row used, so your row six would not get counted because there is no data beyond row 5.  You can replace lastRow with the row number to go to if you know that row but I'm not sure how you know the last blank row that should be counted.

In you VBA IDE go to the tools menu and select references. Select "Microstoft ActiveX data objects 2.8 Library.

We will use a ADODB Recordset to store the data as we find it.

This assumes your list is on Sheet1 and the data is in column A. It will write summary out below the data that is read up.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim szLastData As String

    'Add fields to your recordset for storing data.
    With rs
        .Fields.Append "Value", adChar, 25
        .Fields.Append "Count", adInteger
        .Open
    End With

    'This is getting the last used row in column A
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Loop through the rows
    lRow = 1
    Do While lRow <= lastRow

        'Update the value we will search for in out rs if there is data in the current row
        If ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value <> "" Then
            szLastData = ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value
        End If

        'Check if this is already data that we are counting
        rs.Filter = ""
        rs.Filter = "Value='" & szLastData & "'"

        If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
            'If this is new data, add a new row for it
            rs.AddNew
            rs.Fields("Value").Value = ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value
            rs.Fields("Count").Value = 1
            rs.Update
        Else
            'If we get here, we already have this data.
            'Increment the count by 1
            rs.Fields("Count").Value = rs.Fields("Count").Value + 1
            rs.Update
        End If

    lRow = lRow + 1
    Loop

    'Remove the filer and move to the first record in the rs
    rs.Filter = ""
    rs.MoveFirst

    'Move down a row
    lRow = lRow + 1

    'Loop through the data we found and write a summary
    Do While rs.EOF = False
        ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Value").Value
        ws.Range("B" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Count").Value
        lRow = lRow + 1
    rs.MoveNext
    Loop

End sub
```